# How to get a List<> throug a webmethod to javascript?

Tags: asp.net

I use Page-/WebMethods for handling actuallisize data every x seconds.

Normaly I have 1 Object created on my won, which I get back with 3 informations: time / name / price.

Now I build a site with x members of my object is needed, so:

- can I easily get a List<> of my own object back to JavaScript
- how can I access specific rows, I mean, how I know that the time of row 1 in my list is for time of 1 in the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... ahm... it's nothing special to get Lists back over JavaScript... I only make a funny syntax error.

So if someone is interessted:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     function UpdateAll() 
     {
        setTimeout("UpdateAll()", 99990); 
        PageMethods.Update(OnSucceeded);
     }
     function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) 
     {
            alert(result.detailsList[0].Preis);
     }
```

```
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static object Update()
    {
        Business.AuctionInformationDetails details = new Business.AuctionInformationDetails();


        List<Business.AuctionInformationDetails> detailsList = new List<Business.AuctionInformationDetails>(); ;

        //Fill list

        return new
        {
            detailsList = detailsList
        };
    }
```

(AuctionInformationDetails are only an object with 3 string).

Answer (score 1):

Return the result as [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string and then parse that in client side.

Comment: Can you please add more then one sentence =) Example and how to iterate throug?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think, JavaScript would be able to detect if its a List<>. JSON is the way to send and receive data via PageMethods in ASP.NET Ajax. Did you check this link which uses array to send and receive data, http://forums.asp.net/p/1222967/2198696.aspx#2198696.

Comment: What I meant is, I do not think you would be able to reproduce the exact List<> object in your JavaScript as JavaScript understands just simple array structures in the form of JSON. May I know what exactly your function call would look like from JavaScript? The example which is explained in the link shows how Arraylist can be used in a Pagemethod return parameter.

Comment: I'm sorry, I complete new in JSON. So I have to return time/name/price for x objects over a pagemethod. so, lets say 3 objets, means 9 values. I put the values in my own Object and reaturn it, then I put my object in a list. But as you said javascript can't handle it. How to return 3 objects x3 value over the pagemethod

Comment: Ok, I hope this link http://setiabud.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-pagemethods-json-to-provide-auto.html, would help you understand what I was talking about. You would not get lost here since there are no confusing links in this page :).